# Merging result of two queries

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm making two queries:

```
Dim worker = (From p in db.workers where p.dateAdded > today 
                   select new with{.name = p.name, .desc = p.description})

Dim client = (From p in db.clients where p.dateAdded > today 
                   select new with{.name = p.name, .desc = p.description})
```

How can I merge those two queries to have only one I can use as `DataSource`.

Comment: Is there any relations between the workers and the clients table (like a foreign key) ?

Comment: Nope, it's just a query I want to add to another

Comment: If you have still some problem then update the post with some more code and scenario. SO we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify what exactly you want to do? 

1. Merge the results in one set - if yes, you can use [huMpty duMpty's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925222/humpty-dumpty) proposal

2. If you want to do something similar to DataSet with two DataTables with Linq query I'm not sure if this is achievable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
   Dim Merged = (From p in db.workers where p.dateAdded > today 
                       select new with{.name = p.name, .desc = p.description})
                 .Union
                 (From p in db.clients where p.dateAdded > today 
                       select new with{.name = p.name, .desc = p.description})
```

Comment: I thought it would make it but it can't cast System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`into System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct` if want to get distinct result.

```
var merged = worker.Concat(client).Distinct();
```

or

```
var mergedList = worker.Union(client).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to join those queries. Won't down vote you, since his question is ambiguous.

This is an edit. Concat, right, is kind of a join ^_^ missed that for a moment

Comment: He is asking for union because the properties are same in both the linq results and no column looks like primary key to join these two results.

Comment: @Romil: will this work if **workers** and  **clients** doesn't have same columns??

Comment: If both the results does not have same data type and number of columns then UNION and merge are not possible.

Comment: @Romil: of course, then you **must** mention that on your answer since this not applicable for every cases!!!

Comment: @Romil: Look at it. It select same fields, not all fields from the entities.

Comment: I tried both solutions and it says it can't cast System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`into System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. The table workers and clients hasn't the same structure, thats why I m making a new with{} to select only what I need, and then trying to have two query with the same structure to merge them

Comment: @blop: add **.ToList()** to both selections

Comment: Actually I still have this error: Cant cast System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[Clients]' into 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Workers]'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Union` which provides your expected result.

Have look at [Return the Set Union of Two Sequences (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx)